# kendoui grid nested in popup form

Tags: kendo-grid

I using a kendoui grid to list maintenance jobs and have it set to popup form when editing. on the popup form i have another grid which i want that to list notes associated with the maintenance job. However the 'ADD new record' button on the notes grid opens the a new maintenance popup form instead of the note popup form.

How to i make the 'Add new record' on the notes grid actually open the noted popup form.

Ive attached a screen shot below.

[image]